# How to restrict the HTML tags in multiline textbox?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a **<kbd>Multiline Textbox</kbd>**. I donot want to let user type **<kbd>HTML Tags</kbd>** or validation can be done in the server side. Any suggestions?

When I set `ValidateRequest="true"` it throws error

**potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client**

This is also not required. I tried to put validation by checking the character < but this is also not a proper validation because you can type like `<kanavi and this is not a HTML tag`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set `ValidateRequest="false"`

and handle on the server if there is a tag in input show message.

you can remove the tags

```
 Regex.Replace(source, "<.*?>", string.Empty);
```

OR you use encoding if you want to keep them

Comment: I cannot use `ValidateRequest="false"` as mentioned in my query.

Comment: How can i remove text using `Regex.Replace(source, "<.*?>", string.Empty);`. I mean source can be anything.

Comment: String mystring = Regex.Replace(myinput.Text, "<.*?>", string.Empty);

Comment: how can i make sure that it will replace only proper tags and not <CoDeaDDict></CoDeaDDict> ?

Comment: these  are proper tags.  what do mean by proper tags

Comment: When I said proper tags that means like textarea, asp:textbox, font these are real ones and the above that i mentioned in comment is not the real one. Right?

Comment: then you need to create a method for this, which will check the list of tags inside the input and return the result

Answer (score 0):

Try with regular expression, this is for finding html tags. Use it on application side.

```
Regex.Match(TextBox.Text, "</?\w+((\s+\w+(\s*=\s*(?:".*?"|'.*?'|[^'">\s]+))?)+\s*|\s*)/ >");
```

I have another solution with XDocument always on application side.

Create an XDocument and set a root to it :

```
XDocument yourXDocument = new XDocument(new XElement("Root"));
```

Then load content :

```
yourXDocument.Root = XDocument.Load(TextBox.Text);
```

Then use a recursive function to find if you are more than 2 levels in your XDocument.

Of Couse, if you want to parse only HTML tags, I think you have to create a Dictionary to store all of them and compare your textbox value with each of them.

Comment: how can i make sure that it will replace only proper tags and not `<Aelios></Aelios>`

Comment: Sure but I don't think he wants to store XML tags in his request

Answer (score 0):

have a look at this package from nuget.[HtmlLaundry](http://nuget.org/packages/HtmlLaundry)

it should help you clean out the HTML before it gets to the server.

Comment: can u give me an example how it use it in javascript/code behind to restrict user while saving the HTML data from textbox?

Comment: Sorry this will only work if you are using MVC. it replaces the model binder and you have to have the AllowHTML attribute on the controller.